# How do I get a JSON file to show sub-arrays?

Tags: javascript

I know it's a simple question, but I've tried multiple ways and I can't get it to work. I have a huge JSON file (that I use a reduced version of) which I finally managed to let my script retrieve the file using the `require();` function:

```
let wordBank = './Wordbank.json';

function getData() {
  console.log(require(wordBank));
}
getData();
```

The terminal displays the few lines of my reduced JSON file like this, why?:
[Notice the green "Array"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJBj6.png)

I haven't really been able to find any answer...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Is there a reason you need to log the full array?

Comment: I am a newbie, so I am essentially just experimenting... I also thought that there maybe was a problem since it didn't display the full array but only detected that they were there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use console.dir instead of console.log

`console.dir(data, {depth:100})`

Its having a depth parameter to expand json upto given level

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to JSON string. So you need to change your code like this:

```
let wordBank = './Wordbank.json';
function getData() {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(require(wordBank)));
}
getData();
```